# Rails Activerecord Relation: using subquery as a table for a SQL select statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, subquery

Can somebody help me figure out how to write the following SQL using Rails (I'm using Rails 4) Activerecord methods?  I know you can do this with find_by_sql but I'd like to preserve the active record relation.  Here's the sql for a postGreSQL db that I'm trying to create:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT ON(table_a.id) table_a.name as alias_a, table_b.id, table_b.time
FROM table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
ORDER BY table_a.id, table_b.time asc) AS subquery
ORDER BY alias_a asc
```

For my subquery, I have the following (which generates the sql of the subquery above):

```
@subquery = table_a.select("DISTINCT ON(table_a.id) table_a.name as alias_a, table_b.time")     
@subquery = @subquery.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id")
@subquery = @subquery.order("table_a.id, table_b.time asc")
```

But, I can't figure out how to write a select statement that uses @subquery as the table for the outer select statement.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `from()` method from the Active Record interface.

For example:

```
@subquery = table_a.select("DISTINCT ON(table_a.id) table_a.name as alias_a, table_b.time")     
@subquery = @subquery.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id")
@subquery = @subquery.order("table_a.id, table_b.time asc")
```

Then use it like this in the outer query:

```
@query = OtherModel.from("(#{@subquery.to_sql}) table_name, other_model_table, etc ...").where(:field => table_name.alias_a) ...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks!  For future reference, I found a list of query methods for rails at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from

Answer (score 4):

This one is more elegant:

```
@subquery = Model.balalalala
@query = OtherModel.from(@subquery, :sub_query).where(sub_query: {column_b: balalala}).order('sub_query.column_a')
```